How to manipulate data after a TEXTSPLIT
I am trying to manipulate the results of a TEXTSPLIT I have done.
Formula for reference:
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT($W16,{"[","]"},{",","WorkCenter[ActualQty]:"},TRUE),,)
After splitting the text, my results are as follows:

I am using a SWITCH function to change the operations to have specific letters if their weight value is below the order weight of 3000 lbs. (for this example). Some operations like FINALINSP and SHIPAPPR do not have letters, so even though they are 0, they are blank.If the operation has been completed and has a weight posted, it does not get a letter (referenced below):
=IF(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT($W16,{"[","]"},{",","WorkCenter[ActualQty]:"},TRUE),,2)*1<(0.9*$M16),(SWITCH(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT($W16,{"[","]"},{",","WorkCenter[ActualQty]:"},TRUE),,1),"M400CLEAN","C/","PICKLE","C/","11X3COAT","C","10X2COAT","C","11X1COAT","","DRAW4SHAVE","D","WIREDRAW","D","SHAVE","SH","C/C","C/C","BOXANNEAL","A","PITANNEAL","PA","TANK24","M","COPPER","CU","FINDRAW","DF","SCRAP","","ENGINSP","","PULLMAT","PULL - ","STRIP4SHAV","","STRIP","","FINALINSP","","SHIPAPPR","","IGAINSP","","BLOCK3","D","LABINSP","","S/C&G","S/C&G")),"")

All of this works perfectly, but I want to eliminate the letters from popping up if they are associated to a missed transaction (A missed transaction is when the entered weight is 0, and the next operation has a weight > 0. All operations are sequential, so if the first operation has 0 weight but the next one has a weight greater than 0 , it means that the first transaction must have been completed but not entered in the system).
Additionally, I do not want the cell to spill over as it is doing. So doing a direct cell reference to the spill over cell would not be possible.
For this example, "C/C","PICKLE", and "WIREDRAW" are all missed transactions that have a letter pop up, that should not.
My ideal of what I am looking for would be the following:

Highlighted cells are the ones that I would like blank.
Please help me or reference an article/video that can.
Thank you all!

Can you elaborate on how you identify a missed transaction? Is it simply when the amount is 0? Can you share an image of what your expect output is? the second image shows the false positives you mentioned and the others, and false negatives?

Missing transactions are when the weight entry is 0, and then it is followed up by anything other than zero. If the following step has a weight entry, that means it has been completed. All of these steps are sequential, so that means the previous one MUST have been done.

So looking at the third image, I'm seeing you highlight a few 0's that I presume should have some text? Then I see some zeros that don't have text that aren't highlight. Additionally we see some with non-zeros that do have text? It seems like it'd almost be easier to have a table where you pull in whatever codes you need for text otherwise you'd need to infinitely expand that formula for what I imagine is a changing list?

My apologies, I was not clear enough. If a weight is posted in column 2, the letter should disappear (my apologies, I listed the wrong formula earlier and I have updated it). The highlighted cells are the ones that I do not want anything in. When 90% of the weigh for that step is finished, the letter for that step should disappear.  Since the transaction is missing, excel cannot tell that the step is finished. For reference, the steps at the bottom are not done. Excel is correct to put a letter next to them as they have not been started/finished.

If the issue stems solely from when you want to make things appear why not a IF(And(. Say in C2, If(and(B2=0,b3>0) then go from there, so it will check the current row for 0, the next row for greater than 0 then do your formula as intended. I can't speak to the rules you have on how and what you replace the results to.

As Mark S. suggested, could you try replacing your current formula with this:
=LET(
    split, TEXTSPLIT($W16, {"[", "]"}, {",", "WorkCenter[ActualQty]:"}, TRUE),
    var_1, INDEX(split, , 2),
    var_2, INDEX(split, , 1),
    penultimate_op, "LABINSP",
    comment_1, "A missed transaction is when the entered weight is 0, and the next operation has a weight > 0",
    is_missed_transaction, AND($M16 = 0, var_1 <> penultimate_op, $M17 > 0),
    IFS(
        is_missed_transaction,
        "",
        var_1 * 1 < (0.9 * $M16),
        SWITCH(
            var_1,
            "M400CLEAN", "C/",
            "PICKLE", "C/",
            "11X3COAT", "C",
            "10X2COAT", "C",
            "11X1COAT", "",
            "DRAW4SHAVE", "D",
            "WIREDRAW", "D",
            "SHAVE", "SH",
            "C/C", "C/C",
            "BOXANNEAL", "A",
            "PITANNEAL", "PA",
            "TANK24", "M",
            "COPPER", "CU",
            "FINDRAW", "DF",
            "SCRAP", "",
            "ENGINSP", "",
            "PULLMAT", "PULL - ",
            "STRIP4SHAV", "",
            "STRIP", "",
            "FINALINSP", "",
            "SHIPAPPR", "",
            "IGAINSP", "",
            "BLOCK3", "D",
            "LABINSP", "",
            "S/C&G", "S/C&G"
        ),
        TRUE,
        ""
    )
)

LET function - Microsoft Support
Please let me know if you need more explanation.
